# nvGRAPH undefined reference building example

Tags: c++, makefile, cuda, nvcc, nvgraph

I am trying to execute a nvGRAPH cuda example:

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvgraph/index.html#nvgraph-trianglescounting-example

I saved it as triangle.cu and use my nvcc compiler

```
nvcc -o triangle triangle.cu
```

which yields

```
tmpxft_00004f32_00000000-5_triangle.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `nvgraphCreate'
tmpxft_00004f32_00000000-5_triangle.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x11d): undefined reference to `nvgraphCreateGraphDescr'
tmpxft_00004f32_00000000-5_triangle.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `nvgraphSetGraphStructure'
tmpxft_00004f32_00000000-5_triangle.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1fe): undefined reference to `nvgraphTriangleCount'
tmpxft_00004f32_00000000-5_triangle.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `nvgraphDestroyGraphDescr'
tmpxft_00004f32_00000000-5_triangle.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2bd): undefined reference to `nvgraphDestroy'
```

I think I installed nvgraph correctly as it is linked in `ldconfig -p | grep cuda`

```
libnvgraph.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvgraph.so.10
libnvgraph.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvgraph.so
```

Comment: `nvcc -o triangle triangle.cu -lnvgraph`

Comment: you have to link the nvgraph library